# Struts Form Submission URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, struts2

When I submit a form, the action name appended to the URL (form method type is POST)

Example :

www.application/listclient; on a client list page, add a new client through a popup form.

The url changes to : www.application/listclient?action=addclient

I want the url to be the earlier one : www.application/listclient

Because, in case the form has any errors and I do not want to continue and then I refresh the page, it goes to "addclient" action, not "listclient".

I really thank, if some one shed some light on this.

Thanks.
Sri

Comment: When you pass the parameter to action in the struts.xml, it might pass them in the url.

Comment: Add your jsp and the action configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On HTML5 compliant browser, you can use History PushState API:

```xml
<body>
    <script>
        history.pushState("","","http://www.foo.bar/application/listclient");
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

[The coverage is very wide](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), with few exceptions.

But before going for this, check carefully you are doing everything right in your project, because probably you are not.

You should also learn the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, that is useful to handle cases like your.